# Sub-differential of a sum of non-convex functions

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

For functions, $f_1, f_2, ...$, which are all convex, the sub-differential of their sum is the sum of their sub-differentials,

$\partial \sum\limits_{i} f_i = \sum_\limits{i} \partial f_i$

What could be said about the sub-differential if one or more of these functions are non-convex? Let us ignore the question of whether it is possible to obtain the sub-differential of a particular non-convex function or not.

Comment: Take $f_1(x) = |x|$ and $f_2(x) = -|x|$. Good luck...!

Comment: Does this mean that one cannot conclude anything about the subdifferential of a sum of a functions, if one or more of these functions are non-convex?

Comment: It only means that you have to be careful. There are also some notions for subdifferentials for Lipschitz functions (Frechet, Clarke and Mordukhovich subdifferentials) and for these, some calculus as available.

Comment: Could you point at some references? When searching on google, one mainly comes across presentations/notes that are relevant for only convex functions.

Comment: There are books by Rockafellar/Wets or by Mordukhovich.

Comment: Thank you for the references.